# Discord.py error "discord.errors.ConnectionClosed: Shard ID None WebSocket closed with 4013"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, error-code

So, I have a Discord API named "PySend".

I have the permissions value & token set.

Here's the code:

```
# This example requires the 'message_content' intent.

import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.value = **************
intents.message_content = True
print(intents)

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('***********************************************************************')
```

Based off of [Introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

The `*` parts are my bot's private info that I asterisked out, not what I typed into my program.

I looked at some documentation, that's all.

Comment: seems to be related to [this](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/GatewayCloseCodes#InvalidIntents)

Comment: I gave up on this a long time ago. How do I close this? I already deleted it's bot profile.

Answer (score 1):

the value you set is incorrect.

```
intents.value = **************
```

I don't even know why you even use this line because it's not necessary.

The error code 4013 is for invalid intents value

[Gateway Intents Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents)

but I would recommend you to just don't use this line because it's automatically set.

The [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents%20value#discord.Intents.value) also say to just use the query flags instead of this value.

Comment: As I say in the post:
"
The * parts are my bot's private info that I asterisked out, not what I typed into my program.
".

Comment: The intents shouldn’t be a private part … they are just a number that simbolize the flags you set and your number ist probably incorrect …